# ngrx dispatched action is not reached to effects

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am new in @ngrx. I created a @ngrx action in business-unit.actions.ts and dispatch this action from component. But for some unknown reason, the action is not reaching to the associate effects. I surf stackoverflow and other @ngrx tutorials. I already checked with Redux devtools where `loadSearchBusinessUnits` action is dispatched perfectly but it is not reaching to @ngrx/effects. Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my business-unit.actions.ts file;

```
enum BusinessUnitActionsTypes {
  LoadSearch = '[Business-units] Load Search',
  LoadSearchSuccess = '[Business-units] Load Search Success',
  LoadSearchFailure = '[Business-units] Load Search Failure',
}


export const loadSearchBusinessUnits = createAction(
  BusinessUnitActionsTypes.LoadSearch,
  props<{ search: string }>()
);

export const loadSearchBusinessUnitsSuccess = createAction(
  BusinessUnitActionsTypes.LoadSearchSuccess,
  props<{ businessUnits: BusinessUnit[] }>()
);

export const loadSearchBusinessUnitsFailure = createAction(
  BusinessUnitActionsTypes.LoadSearchFailure,
  props<{ errorMsg: string }>()
);
```

Here is my business-units effects code

```
loadSearchBusinessUnit$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BusinessUnitActions.loadSearchBusinessUnits),
    switchMap(({ search }) => this.businessUnitService.loadBusinessUnitsSearch(search).pipe(
      map((businessUnits: BusinessUnit[]) => {
        return BusinessUnitActions.loadSearchBusinessUnitsSuccess({ businessUnits });
      }),
      catchError(response => of(BusinessUnitActions.loadSearchBusinessUnitsFailure({
        errorMsg: response.error
      })))
    ))
  ));
```

Comment: Did you registered  Effect inside module:https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#registering-root-effects?

Comment: I have already checked it. Effect is registered inside module.

Answer (score 0):

Pass action type inside ofType instead of action object.

```
loadSearchBusinessUnit$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BusinessUnitActions.LoadSearch),
    switchMap(({ search }) => this.businessUnitService.loadBusinessUnitsSearch(search).pipe(
      map((businessUnits: BusinessUnit[]) => {
        return BusinessUnitActions.loadSearchBusinessUnitsSuccess({ businessUnits });
      }),
      catchError(response => of(BusinessUnitActions.loadSearchBusinessUnitsFailure({
        errorMsg: response.error
      })))
    ))
  ));
```